# How to get the time only from timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I have a column of **(created AT)** in my DataFrame which has a timestamps like shown below:

```
      Created AT
1) 2021-04-19T09:14:10.526Z
2) 2021-04-19T09:13:06.809Z
3) 2021-04-19T09:13:06.821Z
```

I want to extract the time only from above column etc . It should show like:
9:14:8 etc
How to extract this ?

Comment: Use `df['created_at'].dt.time`

Comment: Note that `pandas` does not handle date and time separately with the built-in datetime64 datatype (it's always date *and* time). If you want to work efficiently with date and time in pandas, don't slice off the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date column is a string, you need to convert it to datetime and then take a substring of the time:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"Created At":["2021-04-19T09:14:10.526Z","2021-04-19T09:14:10.526Z"]})
df['Created At'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created At'])
df['Created At'] = df['Created At'].dt.time.astype(str).str[:8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created AT'])
print(df['time'].dt.time)
```

On the first line, convert the datetime to objects and write in a new column.

On the second, we get the time from datetime objects

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to your question. It can have multiple solutions but here I am giving some solution here using time, DateTime

---

you can get the string using

```
import time
import datetime
s = '2021-04-19T09:14:10.526Z'
t = s.split('T')[1].split('.')[0]
print(t)
```

and for getting time stamp of it do one more line

```
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(t,"%H:%M:%S"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to datetime and use strftime to format exactly as you like it.

```
data = ['2021-04-19T09:14:10.526Z',
        '2021-04-19T09:13:06.809Z',
        '2021-04-19T09:13:06.821Z']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Created AT'])
df['Created AT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created AT']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print(df)

  Created AT
0   09:14:10
1   09:13:06
2   09:13:06
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the column to datetime format if not already in that format:

```
df['Created AT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created AT'])
```

Then, add the new column `time` with formatting by [`.dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) as follows (if you don't want the nano-second part):

```
df['time'] = df['Created AT'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    
print(df)
    
                        Created AT      time
0 2021-04-19 09:14:10.526000+00:00  09:14:10
1 2021-04-19 09:13:06.809000+00:00  09:13:06
2 2021-04-19 09:13:06.821000+00:00  09:13:06
```